# Apollo update creating duplicate entry in store

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

The HOC wrapper:

```
const CreateAssignmentDialogWithData = compose(
  graphql(CreateAssignmentMutation, {
    props: props => ({
      onAddAssignment: (
        title,
        description,
        assignDate,
        dueDate,
        classId,
        unitId,
        startDate,
        endDate
      ) =>
        props.mutate({
          variables: {
            title: title,
            description: description || "No description",
            assignDate: assignDate,
            dueDate: dueDate,
            classId: classId,
            unitId: unitId
          }
        })
    }),
    options: ({ startDate, endDate, classId }) => ({
      update: (proxy, { data: { putAssignment } }) => {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
          query: ClassFeedQuery,
          variables: {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
            classId: classId
          }
        });
        data.getAssignmentsForClassRange.push(putAssignment);
        proxy.writeQuery({ query: ClassFeedQuery, data });
      }
    })
  }),
```

The mutation works, and the `Assignment` is created in the database, but does not update the UI. Using Apollo Devtools, I can see that the store has two entries for `getAssignmentsForClassRange`. The one being displayed (missing the newly created assignment) is

```
getAssignmentsForClassRange({
  "startDate":"2018-04-16T07:00:00.000Z",
  "endDate":"2018-04-23T06:59:59.999Z",
  "classId":"226b64c4-e585-4703-a446-4515921c94f2"
}): [Assignment]
```

While the one containing the new assignment is displayed as

```
getAssignmentsForClassRange({}): [Assignment]
```

The missing parameters here don't make much sense to me, as it still retrieves the correct assignments (including the new one). How would I go about making my `update` append the new assignment directly to the query instead of creating this new one? Or is there another way I could achieve live UI updates?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do. Apollo has a section on how to update the store/cache from mutation results, maybe that helps: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#directAccess
Edit: React link here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update

Comment: You write to cache store a new query, so it can't update your UI. `proxy.readQuery` must have same query and parameters with `proxy.writeQuery`